# creating userprofile programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I was just creating an instance of a userprofilemanager and i get an error in the same line

UserProfileManager myuserprofilemanager = new UserProfileManager(mycontext, true, true);

Error is - 
"UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have 0d3993c7-9fe0-46b6-ae17-241e6d502bd3"

Any help is highly appreciated.

The stach trace tells at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights rights, Boolean requireAllRights)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights rights)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.CanManagePeople(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_IsProfileAdmin()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.get_IsProfileAdmin()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.b_*0() in \aucfsrv.auc.ab.ca\hdrives\u50038\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b__3()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)

i have set full control User Profile Service Application permission for  for the user under which application is running

Comment: Show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rechecked the Configuration of the user profile and it worked.. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Can you add more details? What did you change in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue for me:

◾Open Central Administration
◾Click Service Applications
◾Select “User Profile Service Application”
◾Click in ribbon the Permissions button
◾Add account which is running PS script, in this example “xxx-spinstall”
◾Select “Full Control” and click OK
◾Run the PS-script again!

Source: https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/when-setting-the-mysitehosturl-i-get-a-userprofileapplicationnotavailableexception/